# Cannot setup NumberPicker in Fragment

Tags: android, android-number-picker

So I have a NumberPicker defined in XML, which I'm trying to populate. I believe I've got all of the setup done correctly, however when running the app, the picker is set to 0 and cannot be altered.

This is inside a fragment, if this makes any difference.

The code is as follows:

```
private void setupNumberPicker(View view){
    NumberPicker picker = view.findViewById(R.id.vocabNumberPicker);
    int wordCount = ((Globals) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getDictSize();

    String[] values = new String[wordCount - Constants.MINIMUM_WORDS_REQUIRED_FOR_TEST + 1];
    int k = 0;
    System.out.println("VALUES REQUIRED: " + values.length);
    for(int i = Constants.MINIMUM_WORDS_REQUIRED_FOR_TEST; i < wordCount + 1; i++){
        System.out.println("DEBUG - Loop" + k);
        System.out.println("DEBUG - i = " + i);
        values[k] = Integer.toString(i);
        k++;
        System.out.println("Successful\n");
    }
    picker.setMaxValue(wordCount);
    picker.setMinValue(Constants.MINIMUM_WORDS_REQUIRED_FOR_TEST);
    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(values);
    picker.setValue(Constants.MINIMUM_WORDS_REQUIRED_FOR_TEST);
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: VALUES REQUIRED: 4
I/System.out: DEBUG - Loop0
DEBUG - i = 2
Successful
I/System.out: DEBUG - Loop1
I/System.out: DEBUG - i = 3
I/System.out: Successful
I/System.out: DEBUG - Loop2
DEBUG - i = 4
Successful
DEBUG - Loop3
DEBUG - i = 5
Successful
```

NumberPicker in the XML (just in case it helps):

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/vocabNumberPicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vocabHowManyQuestionsTextView"/>
```

The setupNumberPicker is called from onCreateView

Comment: Please post your `onCreateView` code. You are possibly again double-inflating the view. 

Comment: I need to stop programming when exhausted. Thank you kindly @lionscribe . Please don't hate me :P

Comment: Nah, Good programmers program until they drop!